# Extract a String from a Column using SQL

Tags: sql

Can someone help me with ways in SQL to extract a particular string after a word from a column? Below see the below examples for complete understanding.

[image]

Here the column is `comments`. I need to introduce two more fields from this column [yet retain the column `comments`] which are `quality` and `detail`. So my two fields should look like:

[image]

Can some one help me on how to extract the fields `quality` and `detail` from `comments` using SQL? Should we use substring

Also, There are values where comments doesnt have `details` nor `quality` in its values. Samples below. The solution must also accomodate when there is no `details` nor `quality` which means, no values should be fetched for this case.

| comments |
| --- |
| Honestly? Well here goes how good it s. |
| My duties should be in UK |
| I look forward to hearing from you |
| I didn't want to be responsible for any more bad data of having physical copies |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, we cannot cut and paste from an image nor can everyone view an image. You've also tagged multiple database plarforms, tag the RDBMS you are *actually* using.

Comment: Yes [`substring` with regex](https://popsql.com/learn-sql/postgresql/how-to-use-substring-with-regular-expressions-in-postgresql) will be a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, let's preparar sample data (that should be done by you in next questions, please):

```
create table MyTable  (
  comments varchar(500),
  quality varchar(500),
  detail varchar(500)
)

insert into MyTable (comments) values (':comments: person´s particular genre anyway :quality: spam user. No good :detail: nothing to do with the person. More of an organization')
insert into MyTable (comments) values (':comments: One of the first things :quality: Good thing, cool :detail: value02')
insert into MyTable (comments) values (':comments: name changed incorrectly :quality: No association :detail: No further details')
insert into MyTable (comments) values (':comments: This little game of yours is going to end :quality: Best so far by comments :detail: Had a full rematch but no use')
```

Once we have that done, we can update the two new fields with the wanted values:

```
update MyTable
set quality = SUBSTRING(
    comments,
    CHARINDEX(':quality:', comments) + LEN(':quality:') + 1,
    CHARINDEX(':detail:', comments) - CHARINDEX(':quality:', comments) - LEN(':detail:') - 3
),
detail = SUBSTRING(
    comments,
    CHARINDEX(':detail:', comments) + LEN(':detail:') + 1,
    LEN(comments)
)
```

And finally we check everything has gone well:

```
select quality, detail from MyTable
```

This will return this:

```
|                 quality |                                                 detail |
|-------------------------|--------------------------------------------------------|
|      spam user. No good | nothing to do with the person. More of an organization |
|        Good thing, cool |                                                value02 |
|          No association |                                     No further details |
| Best so far by comments |                          Had a full rematch but no use |
```

SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/e3cac/1

Comment: Thank YOu Carlos, it defn helped. There are cases in comments where there is no quality and detail values. For such cases, the above soln fails.. trying to figure out what can be done for such situations.. You can help?

Comment: @user3624000 Yes, I can help, but give some sample data, please. What are those cases when there is not quality or details? Just null values?

Comment: Added in the post desc. The `comments` field will basically have values but there wont be `quality` and `quality` in it which means, the `quality` and `details` should have no values.

Comment: @user3624000 in that case you could add a WHERE clause in the update: 
update MyTable
set quality = SUBSTRING(
    comments,
    CHARINDEX(':quality:', comments) + LEN(':quality:') + 1,
    CHARINDEX(':detail:', comments) - CHARINDEX(':quality:', comments) - LEN(':detail:') - 3
),
detail = SUBSTRING(
    comments,
    CHARINDEX(':detail:', comments) + LEN(':detail:') + 1,
    LEN(comments)
)
WHERE ISNULL(CHARINDEX(':detail:', comments), 0) != 0

Comment: Thank You Carlos. The solution was in mind as well - I think ISNULL is the best solution we can do to handle both the cases.